# How do I decide the attributes and operations that a class will be responsible for in a design class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case

I am trying to create a design class diagram based on the use case below:

Preconditions: User is logged in

1. The system presents the list of expense claims that have been authorised for payment.
2. The user selects an expense claim from the list.
3. The system shows all the items recorded under it.
4. The user selects one of two options: (a) to confirm the claim for payment, or (b) to review
   it further.
5. IF option (a) is selected THEN

5.1 The system records the confirmation of payment and notifies the accounts
department.

ELSE
5.2 DO EXTEND Review Claim

END IF

How do I decide which class (between account and system) is responsible for which attributes and operations? Do I decide based on my own interpretation or is there an established method?

This is what I have so far: [design class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScTjX.png)

Comment: Design decisions are based on long-year experience. The only thing I can say about your draft is that `System` is a bad name for a class.

Answer (score 2):

Designing a class diagram is usually something that is open to the interpretation of the person making it. Not sure about other methods of going about this, but this is how I usually approach this problem:

1. Identify the types of objects (i.e. classes) that exist within the scenario. These are individual items that exist within your scenario (e.g. User, ExpenseClaim, ExpenseItem). A good practice for identifying these are items that usually have pieces of data (i.e. properties) or perform a function (i.e. methods). In general, you may want to err on the side of identifying as many things as possible as the idea is that each class is supposed to do a specific thing and no more than that (you will probably revise this when carrying out the later steps). However, don't confuse objects with actors - the system is actually what the whole class diagram explains so it should never be considered as a class.
2. For each type of object, look at the data they contain and translate them into either properties or relations onto other types of object. Really try and limit the amount of data that each object has; if one object has a lot of properties, it is probably ripe for splitting it up into multiple objects. Taking the example of ExpenseClaim and ExpenseItem, its clear that each ExpenseClaim has a list of ExpenseItem, so you might want to link these with a composition arrow.
3. Now lastly look at each one and think about the things that other objects might try and do to change the data that the object has - this will probably be your methods. For an ExpenseClaim object it will probably have a confirm() method for changing the state of an isConfirmed::boolean property. Again, really try and limit the amount of functionality to the specific role that the object plays - if an object has too many functions or a function that doesn't really suit it, it probably means that there is another (new) object that will suit it better.